# Is there a way to add finally to an existing promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localforage

I am using localforage which returns a promise for functions such as key() and length(). I am also using $http() which returns a promise for too but it includes a finally() function, which the other does not.

My services down the chain do not know whether localforage or $http makes the request so they all require the same promise structure (finally and then). Is there a way to add finally to the promises that do not already have it?

I have attempted to append $q.defer().promise.finally to my promises from localforage which did not work.

```
var promise = localforage.length();
promise.finally = $q.defer().promise.finally;
return promise;
```

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You should be able to convert into a standard promise by doing.. `Promise.resolve(someNoneStandardPromise)`  And then do a `catch` followed by a `then`

Comment: Still didn't do it for me. The promise returns and the then function executes but I get the error `(...).finally is not a function`

Comment: Use standard promises, finally is not standard.  Do `catch` and `then` like I said.

Comment: [ES Proposal spec-compliant shim for Promise.prototype.finally](https://github.com/es-shims/Promise.prototype.finally)

Comment: Even if not the correct solution, I need the promise to have a finally. Countless services and controllers already have `finally` implemented. Need a faster solution in the meantime, if possible.

Comment: Just a note!!,  When using Promises, a really nice extension is using async / await.  Here Javascript's normal finally works as expected, apart from easier to read code, async await has some extra guards built in, eg. An async function is guaranteed to return a Promise..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to "convert" one promise into another you can use their `resolve` method to resolve an inner promise (or to adopt the value of the promise). For `$q` you can use the [resolve method here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve). So basically:

```
return $q.resolve(localforage.length());
```

There's also [`Promise.prototype.finally`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally) coming up soon, so you can scratch `$q` and use native `Promise` with a [shim](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally). All you got to do is literally use `Promise` instead of `$q` (literally).

Comment: The change involves legacy code, so need a solution that still uses finally.

Comment: @jrquick well it will if you use a shim, that's the point of the shim.

Comment: @jrquick the returned promise will have a `finally` method

Comment: @MinusFour You're correct. I tried `Promise.resolve` first, instead of `$q.resolve`. But then I re read, thank you!